# Comparing nouns

Tags: grammar, particle-と, particle-か

Good day,

I would like some clarification with regards to comparing nouns. In some references like Minna no Nihongo, the sentence formula would be something like

> A と B と + どちら のほうが/が + Adjectiveですか。
>
> Example: 太陽と月とどちらが大きですか。
> Which one is bigger, the sun or the moon?

But when I was watching a [Japanese From Zero YouTube clip](https://youtu.be/1anHQbtV4os?t=617), か was used instead of と and the last と was omitted.

> Japanese From Zero example: 太陽か月どちらが大きですか。

I am still a beginner, and for now what I've learned was that か is used as a particle to indicate question, and と was used to join nouns. I was just wondering why か is acceptable in this example. Thank you in advance!

Comment: か can also mean "or",  usually particles have many usages. So when learning them, it is good to keep an open mind because you'll soon realize you can use them in many different ways.

Comment: Some particles can have completely different meanings, but か in the sense of 'or' is clearly related to the final particle for questions. と as 'and' and 'with' have related meanings as well. These meanings are easier to remember because they are similar.